# Mapping a userId to it's associated email

Tags: google-bigquery

When I run the following command in the Console it returns a column titled "userId" (which is a [deprecated](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs#TransferConfig) field). How do I map this userId to its email address or username?

```
<REDACTED>@cloudshell:~ (project-id)$ bq show \ 
--transfer_config \
projects/<XXX>/locations/europe/transferConfigs/<XXX>
```

The returned value for userID is a 19-character integer.

Reason for this question is that we have a large number of scheduled queries and transfers and would like to know the account whose credentials are being used.

I previously asked this question on [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/994258/mapping-a-userid-to-its-associated-email) and was encouraged to post here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to map each user id with an email or service account, in addition, if the parameter is deprecated I don't recommend using it because it might disappear.

However, as workaround you could create a new sink in Bigquery [1] with the logs you want to obtain information, for example, in your case I would create a sink with these filters:

> resource.type="bigquery_resource"
>
> protoPayload.requestMetadata.callerSuppliedUserAgent="BigQuery DataTransfer Service"
>
> protoPayload.methodName="jobservice.jobcompleted"

Therefore, each time a Bigquery tranfer is launched, the sink will export each log to the selected Bigquery dataset with a large amount of information that you can use to your use case, such as the "authenticationInfo" indicating the user or service account who executed that transfer.

Since the data is stored in a table in Bigquery, you can create new queries and get the information that best suits your work each time. For example:

```
SELECT 
protopayload_auditlog.servicedata_v1_bigquery.jobCompletedEvent.job.jobName.jobId as 
JOB_ID, protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail as USER
FROM `<TABLE>`
group by JOB_ID, USER
```

[1] https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export_v2#dest-create